# Unable to get default working with haxe.Web.Dispatch

Tags: haxe

I am currently setting up a website using haxe targetting php and I'm having a problem with the [haxe.Web.Dispatch](http://haxe.org/manual/dispatch) library.

Everything was working well until I tried to implement a doDefault() rule.

I have the following rules in my dispatch api:

```
doIndex(){ ... }

doPosts(){y:String, m:String, n:String){ ... }
```

And these will both redirect to the correct webpage. For example these both work fine:

```
http://foo.com/index
http://foo.com/posts/2013/01/post-title
```

And now I've implemented

```
doDefault() {...}
```

in order to redirect any other urls to a 404 page, but it's not working. Going to the above URLs still works fine but going to

```
http://foo.com/bar
```

gives the following error

```
uncaught exception: DETooManyValues

in file: C:\wamp\www\website\bin\lib\haxe\web\Dispatch.class.php line 191
#0 C:\wamp\www\website\bin\lib\Index.class.php(9): haxe_web_Dispatch->runtimeDispatch(Object(_hx_anonymous))
#1 C:\wamp\www\website\bin\lib\Index.class.php(12): Index->__construct()
#2 C:\wamp\www\website\bin\index.php(9): Index::main()
#3 {main}
```

The Dispatch [documentation](http://haxe.org/manual/dispatch) says

> In case the corresponding method doXXXX is not found on the api
>   object, or if the URL is /, the action doDefault is used instead. An
>   exception DispatchError.DENotFound("XXXX") is thrown if there is no
>   default action (XXXX here being the placeholder for the URL part
>   name).

but it doesn't say anything about the DETooManyValues exception. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DETooManyValues` error is thrown if the URL you are dispatching has more parts than the matching action.

So if you have:

```
doPage( name:String );
```

Then by default "/page/aboutus/" will work, but "/page/aboutus/2/" will not.  This applies for `doDefault()` too - "/" will work, "/bar" will not (by default).

The trick to getting this to work is using a "Dispatch" argument.

```
doPage( name:String, d:haxe.web.Dispatch ) {
    trace('Get page $name, with other parts: ${d.parts}');
}
doDefault( d:haxe.web.Dispatch ) {
    trace('Get page $name, with other parts: ${d.parts}');
}
```

If `Dispatch` knows that your action/method has this dispatch argument, then it assumes your method knows how to deal with the extra values, and will no longer throw the error.  You can use the `d.parts` array to access the extra parts.

Added bonus:

You can also use the `d:Disaptch` argument to:

```
// Redirect to a different page, same get/post parameters
d.redirect("/differentpage/", d.params); 

// Redirect to a different controller.  If this is in /doDefault/, the whole URL is passed to the sub-controller.  
// If it is in `doPage` and the URL is /page/some/other/part, only `/some/other/part` will be passed on.
d.dispatch(new SomeOtherController());
```

I have a blog post which explains some more stuff if you're interested:

http://jasononeil.com.au/2013/05/29/creating-complex-url-routing-schemes-with-haxe-web-dispatch/

Also feel free to keep asking questions, always keen to help someone else using Haxe for websites :)

Comment: Aha, I hadn't realised in "/bar" the bar gets passed as a part, rather than getting matched by doDefault itself. And yes the dispatch argument is super useful. Thanks for the thorough answer and the blog post!

Comment: If you have `doDefault( ?part:String )` you should be able to match both "/" and "/bar/", but not "/bar/foo/"... I think :)